# select data in specific week

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

How to select data between today and the next 7 days

Comment: look up the t-sql keywords/functions `BETWEEN`, `GetDate()`, and `DATEADD`.

Comment: Keep in mind that getting the date range of a specific week and getting a date range for the next 7 days are different actions. You will get unexpected results if you expect one but query for another.

Comment: For the duplicate just change -7 to 7. Dateadd(day,7,getdate())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the comments says between and DATEADD should help you.

```
SELECT Created_Date, GETDATE() as Curr_Date FROM MY_TABLE WHERE Created_Date between GETDATE() and  DATEADD(day,7, GETDATE())
```